# What's The React Way To Handle Shared Helper Functions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm somewhat new to React, and I'm trying to figure out where the best place is to put various functions that need to be used across my app.

For example, I have a function some code that returns a `document_type` key based on the document extension that is passed to it.

I also have a `romanize` function that takes a number and turns it into a roman numeral.

I also have a set of functions that are grouped around making API calls and parsing the response.

All of these need to be accessed in various places across the app. It's my understanding that the "React Way" is composability through component creation, but it's hard for me to see how these would make sense as components since components have to return JSX I believe.

Comment: You could create e.g. a `utils` file, export your helpers from there, and import them when needed. `import { romanize } from './utils';`

Comment: If they don't have inherently anything to do with a specific component, don't make it. Just isolate them in a `utils` file and import as necessary where needed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could create e.g. a `utils` file, export your helpers from there, and import them when needed:

```
// utils.js

export function romanize(str) {
  // ...
}

export function getDocumentType(doc) {
  // ...
}

// App.js

import { romanize } from './utils';
```

Answer (score 2):

There are some situations where you will need a helper functions like these and setting those up in a util or helpers folder is a great way to handle that.

However, to take full advantage of React, I'd suggest thinking about if there is a way you could make a shared component instead. For functions such as your romanize function, you can make a React component that formats the number you pass it and displays it in a span. This is the same approach react libraries use, for example the `react-intl` library recommends using their `<FormattedMessage />` component instead of their `formatMessage` helper function.

For example,

```
const RomanNumeral = ({ number }) => {
    // romanize logic here
    return <span>{result}</span>
}
```

Then you can use it like so:

```
<RomanNumeral number={5} />
```

Answer (score 1):

The "react way" is to structure these files in the way that makes most sense for your application. Let me give you some examples of what react applications tend to look like to help you out.

React has a declarative tree structure for the view, and other related concepts have a tendency to fall into this declarative tree structure form as-well.

Let's look at two examples, one where the paradigm relates to the view hierarchy and one where it does not.

For one where it does not, we can think about your domain model. You may need to structure local state in stores that resemble your business model. You business model will usually look different from your view hierarchy, so we would have a separate hierarchy for this.

But what about the places where the business model needs to connect to the view layer. Since we are specifying data on a per component bases. Even though it isn't the view or styles or how the component behaves, this is still colocated in the same folder hierarchy as the react component because it fits into the same conceptual structure.

Now, there is your question of utilities. There are many approaches to this.

1. If they are all small and specific to your application but not any part, you can put them in the root under utils.
2. If there are a lot of utils and they fit into a structure separate from any of your existing hierarchies, make a new hierarchy.
3. If they are independent from your application, either of the above approaches could become an npm package.
4. If they relate to certain parts of your app, you can put them at the highest point in the hierarchy such that everything that uses the utility is beneath the directory where the utility lives.

Answer (score 0):

Shared Conmponents is definetly the react way but having reusable functions in the utility/helper folder is always handy.
Here is how I would do it.

You could create a `utility` folder inside `src` folder where you could export all the reusable functions

```
--| src

----| utility
-------| formatDate.js
-------| formatCurrency.js
-------| romanize.js

----| components
----| hooks
----| api
```

Then you could import the functions inside your components